# Histogram in R Program

Tags: r, histogram, extent

I have created a histogram to show LULC by pixel values. The code I used is:-

```
library(raster)
RupandehiLULC19<-raster('C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/EM/RupandehiLULC2.tif')
plot(RupandehiLULC19)
hist(RupandehiLULC19, main="Boxplot of LULC By Pixel Value", xlab="Pixel Value", 
las=1,col=c("green"))
```

The map displayed is:-

[image]

Though the histogram is displayed it looks congested , text is overlapping (i.e. frequency overlapping with number value) & one column of pixel value higher than frequency label. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Make the plotting window larger.

Comment: @AllanCameron- Doesn't this need code? I got the same problem when I zoomed this histogram in new window.

Comment: The aspects of base graphics are controlled by the `par` function. You may want to increase the "mar" settngs from their default values. See `?par` and maybe `?plot.default`

Comment: @Quinten, I don't think this will add any information to your questions for raster image. The dput when I applied for Raster Data Yield:-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try e.g. increasing the range of values in the y axis with `ylim`, and changing `las` to 3 to avoid the axis labels overlapping the axis title:

`hist(RupandehiLULC19, main="Boxplot of LULC By Pixel Value", xlab="Pixel Value", las=3, col=c("green"), ylim = c(0, 80000))`